# PHP error unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

im working on a piece of code and it comes up with this error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /admin.php on line 44 
This is my first php script, it worked fine untill i changed it so it would save the input into php, now it says this... dont get angry if its a stupid mistake ive just started learning. Line 44 starts with $filename

Heres my code

```
         <?php

   if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-        transitional.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Micro News</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="main">
    <div id="caption">Micro News - Add news</div>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        News title:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="title" size="40"/><br/><br/>
        Content:<br/>
        <textarea name="newstext" rows="15" cols="67"></textarea><br/>
        <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></center>
     </form> 

     <div id="source">Micro News 1.0</div>
  </div>
</body>   

<?php } else {
   $newsTitel   = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'Untitled';
   $submitDate  = date('Y-m-d');
   $newsContent = isset($_POST['newstext']) ? $_POST['newstext'] : 'No content';

   $filename = ($newsTitel".php");
   $f = fopen('news/'.$filename.);         
    fwrite($f,$newsTitel."\n");
   fwrite($f,$submitDate."\n");
   fwrite($f,$newsContent."\n");
   fclose($f);

   header('Location:index.php');   
}
?>
```

Comment: And how does line 44 differ from the following lines where a variable and a string part get concatenated?

Answer (score 1):

What is this?

```
$filename = ($newsTitel".php");
```

Did you mean

```
$filename = $newsTitel . ".php";
// or
$filename = ($newsTitel . ".php");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = ($newsTitel".php");
```

It tells you the error is here. It takes two seconds to notice that it should be:

```
$filename = ($newsTitel.".php");
// missing dot here ---^
```

Comment: Next error will be in next line `$f = fopen('news/'.$filename.);`